# Django not searching correct table name for custom user model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to use a custom user model in my Django project. After running migrations, the database table is named `accounts_listuser` while Django appears to be looking for them in `accounts_user`. How can I change this so Django looks at the correct table (`accounts_user`) for the user model instead of `accounts_listuser`?

In my settings.py:

```
# Auth user models
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'accounts.authentication.PersonaAuthenticationBackend'
)
```

The accounts/models.py file:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    is_authenticated = True
    is_anonymous = False
```

And the file (accounts/authentication.py) where the query fails:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

# .. user's email retrieved ..

    def get_user(self, email):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

The full source code [can be found here](https://github.com/DigitalMockingbird/tdd) if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by `correct table` in this case, but this behavior sounds about right since your model is called user and is declared in an app named accounts.

You can overwrite the auto-generated table name using class `Meta` attribute `db_table`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#db-table

Also just a note, the django docs recommend that your custom user model inherits from `AbstractBaseUser`, otherwise you will be responsible for implementing quite a few things on your own. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Excellent answer. Just to add a little bit more information: If you inherit from AbstractBaseUser you'll probably also want to look into inheriting PermissionsMixin too if some of these users need admin access, etc.